# Mysql Left outer join mostrar apenas o primeiro resultado

Tags: mysql, mysqli

estou precisando fazer esse join da tabela vendas com a tabela Nfe, porem a tabela NFE pode ter mais de um resultado o que ocasiona alteração no total de vendas, como posso alterar esse join para que pegue apenas a ultima nota?

```
select 
sum(total_venda) as total_venda
from vendas v 
LEFT OUTER JOIN nfe n ON (v.cod_venda = n.cod_venda and n.status like 'Emitida' and n.excluido is null)
```

Comment: Atualizei a resposta de acordo com a sua necessidade.

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade ele não mostra somente o primeiro resultado. Ele está mostrando o que você está pedindo ( a soma da coluna total_venda).
Sendo uma soma o valor é agrupado, logo não vai mostrar mais de um resultado mesmo.

Para pegar apenas a última nota, retire o SUM e dê um order by DESC pelo cod_venda ou se tiveres uma data por ela.
Ficaria algo como

```
select 
total_venda as total_venda
from vendas v 
LEFT OUTER JOIN nfe n ON (v.cod_venda = n.cod_venda and n.status like 'Emitida' and n.excluido is null)
Order by v.cod_venda desc limit 1
```

Comment: No caso eu precisaria que entrasse no sum apenas uma nota, pois pode ocorrer da mesma venda ter mais de uma nota

Comment: Então não é [***'(...) apenas a ultima nota'***](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/311529/78713). Para o que você perguntou @VictorMangia, essa resposta atende. Se você esclarecer a sua pergunta talvez o AR ou outra pessoa possa ajudá-lo melhor.

Comment: @VictorMangia troque o v.cod_venda pelo campo de número da nota de sua tabela de notas, e adicione o limit 1 conforme o exemplo. Deve solucionar.